# react.js image onClick not working for some reason, while same function works for another div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i am making Faq questions in react and my question div displays text when clicked on whole body as shown below:
[image: Question body before click]

[image: Question after clicked]

Here is my react code. div with class "question-body" works with onclick but when I click the Plus img it has no action,any mistakes?

```
export default function Question({data}){
let imagid = 'img'+data.id;

function toggle(){
        document.getElementById(data.id).classList.toggle('question-p') ;
        document.getElementById(imagid).classList.toggle('rotateimg');
}


return(
    <div className="column width100 question">
        <div onClick={() => toggle()} className="question-body">
             <div className="flex-between">
                 <label className="faq-question">{data.question}</label>
                 <img onClick={() => toggle()} id={imagid} className='togglequestion'  src={togglequestion}></img>
             </div>
             <p id={data.id} className='none' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.answer }}></p>
        </div>

    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

even though the answer is pretty simple here, it would require you to redo most of your code.

In order to be working with React.js effectively, you need to learn the basics (component state management,... ) - https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

I highly encourage you not to use ***dangerouslySetInnerHTML*** as it can expose your code to easy exploits.

With React.js, you don’t really want to use Document Object Model APIs (via toggle function)